# Proxy authentication required (http error 407) with WinHttpRequest and proxy with integrated Windows authentication and https

Tags: vba, https, proxy, winhttprequest, http-status-code-407

I'm trying to access an external website from my company network using `WinHttpRequest` from VBA. The company has a proxy server that requires integrated Windows authentication.

The following code works if I try to access a URL with plain http, but I get http status code `407 - proxy authentication required` if I try to access a URL with https.

What do I need to do to make the code work with https?

```
Sub a()
    Dim w As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    'set proxy        
    w.SetProxy 2, "myproxy:8080"
    'use integrated windows authentication
    w.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
    w.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    w.Open "GET", "https://..."
    w.Send
    Debug.Print w.Status ' Status = 407
    Debug.Print w.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_URL)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, please insert (between `Open` and `Send`) a line for setting credentials and another one for ignoring (all) SSL errors. Try something lile that:

```
Sub AccessSiteThroughProxy()
    Dim w As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    'set proxy
    w.setProxy 2, "myproxy:8080"
    'use integrated windows authentication
    w.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
    w.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    w.Open "GET", "https://..."

    'try inserting a line to set credentials:________________________________________
     w.SetCredentials UserName, Password, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER ' try Const HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0
     'in order to ignore SSL erors, try:
     w.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300
    '_________________________________________________________________________________

    w.send
    Debug.Print w.Status ' Status = 407
    Debug.Print w.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_URL)
End Sub
```

Comment: SetCredentials will be a problem because it requires username and password entered in clear text, which is not allowed by company security policy. I'll try the ignore ssl error flag.

Comment: Ups... Then, try replacing of the the line setting credentials with `w.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0`. I am not connected through a proxy to test it... I would also try `w.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_OnlyIfBypassProxy`... Having a correct reference, it should use the appropriate constant value, I think.

Comment: @Shadow: Did you find time to check if `SetAutoLogonPolicy` changed something in the code behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the ssl ignore errors, nor the change in the authentication helped. However, what I did observe during the test, that for some URLs https works, for some it does not. Maybe something to do with ssl / tls level required, will check.

Comment: I would try playing with `w.Option(` and choose from options offered by intellisense. You maybe will find something able to solve your problem. Good luck! I will delete my answer after you confirm that read my suggestion...